# Using Bundles in Laravel Migrations

Tags: migration, bundle, laravel

I want to use sentry 1.x with Laravel 3.x in the migrations I use, but when I try to migrate I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Sentry' not found in /var/www/laravel.dev/application/migrations/2013_03_06_183713_add_user_to_database.php on line 34
```

This is what I try to do in function up():

```
$user_id = Sentry::user()->create(array(
    'email' => 'admin@test.com',
    'password' => 'testpass',
    'metadata' => array(
    'first_name' => 'Test',
    'last_name' => 'Test'
    )
));
```

What am I missing ?

p.s: I know having the password in PHP is insecure, this is just a test environment.

Thanks,

Comment: Just dropping this one: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel ;)

Comment: @Kriem I didn't know about the site, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start the bundle.

```
Bundle::start( 'sentry' );
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I was too hasty before marking as accepted, OK, it calls the bundle, but bundle itself throws me an exception when I try to migrate: "A driver must be set before using the session."

Comment: This may be an issue with using Sessions from the command line. The Session class has a number of possible SessionDrivers. I could see this being a problem if you were configured to use Cookies but perhaps File or Database Sessions would work.

Comment: Well, just for a sample migration I won't change the authentication mechanism. I also posted the issue on Laravel forums, I hope something will pop up.

Comment: Session != Auth. Look in application/config/session.php If you really want to leave things as is you can setup a separate environment for the CLI... something like --set-environment=cli and then application/config/cli/session.php. I'm 99% sure your issue is that it is trying to use cookies to store session data but you aren't accessing the script from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'Cartalyst\Sentry\SentryServiceProvider' to the list of service providers in app/config/app.php